# Have parameters in Dao methods to get entities the most efficient way for read-only access

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

Allot of my use of hibernate, at least for that data that is presented on many parts of the web application, is for read-only purposes.

I want to add some parameters to my Dao methods so I can modify the way hibernate pulls the data and how it handles transactions etc.

**By 'pulls the data' I altering the locking and not having session worry about monitoring changes to the entities since I want read-only, read-uncommited (and any other performance tweaks there are?).**

Example usage:
Data on the front page of my website is displayed to the users, it is read-only, so I want to avoid any session/entity tracking that hibernate usually does.

This is data that is read-only, will not be changed in this transaction, etc.

What would be the most performant way to pull the data?

**(the code below is c#/nhibernate, I'm implementing this in java as I learn it)**

```
public IList<Article> GetArticles()
{
    return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Article))
                  // some where cluase
}
```

Comment: it isn't clear what you want to do. Furthermore, your example doesn't look like Java.

Comment: Look like NHibernate which is indeed not Java at all. Please update your question, tags and/or code accordingly to align it all out.

Comment: I want to do it in Java, just making a transition.

Comment: @Bozho I want to add parameters to the method so I have the option of pulling the data the most efficient/fastest way for cases when I don't need transactions/locking etc., purely read-only with even read-uncommitted locking.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful as to why there is no session.setReadOnly method

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2672

Alternatively have a look at stateless session http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession but be informed that there is no first level cache or second level cache support for this (so this might actually turn out to be a bad thing for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, well I guess I could add the object to ehcache myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use **select new** clause.

As said by JPA specification

> The resulting entity instances **are in the new state**.

Be aware The constructor name **must be fully qualified**.

So you can use

```
select new br.com.model.domain.User(u) from User u
```

You should provide a constructor like this one

```
public class User {

    private String name;

    // required no-arg constructor
    public User() {}

    public User(User u) {
        this.name = u.name;

         // And so on...
    }

}
```

Or use either Spring BeanUtils or Apache Commons BeanUtils instead as follows

```
public User(User u) {
    // Spring BeanUtils
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(u, this);

    // Apache Commons BeanUtils
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read-only session in hibernate:

```
Session session = ... // Hibernate session
session.connection().setReadOnly(true);
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.NEVER);
// Your query...
session.connection().setReadOnly(false);
session.close();
```

Alternatively, you could simply rollback your transaction and nothing will get flushed (and no dirty check will be done).